# bash file to send an e-mail in unix?

Tags: unix, bash, command-line-interface, sendmail, aix

i want to write bash file perform the following steps :-

copy file from `server1` to `server2`

if (copy success )

do nothing

if (copy failed )

send e-mail to `admin@company.com` contain the following information

file name [copy failed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On server1 --

```
SOURCE=a.txt
DEST=a.txt
R_HOST=server2

scp $SOURCE $R_HOST:$DEST || mutt -s "[copy failed] Copy of $SOURCE failed" admin@company.com
```

Requires you have [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) installed. If you don't, get mutt, or replace the mutt portion with a `sendmail` alternative.

Comment: Almost all variants of Unix and Linux (including AIX) include the ancient `mail` program. You can just replace `mutt` with `mail` in your command and get the same result and it's basically guaranteed to work.

Comment: @mattdm - agreed. No reason to create an un-needed dependency here.

Comment: cool, thanks guys. i use mutt every day, so it's my go-to... Osama, do what they say :)

Comment: thanks for all ... i used `mail` because i didn't install `mutt` :)